# style.css is not loaded in other template files than index.php (eg. front-page.php)

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I am a Wordpress newbie who just started to go through this tutorial: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#stylesheets

So i created a new theme and activated it.

Theme structure is a basic one:

```
elitetheme
 -> front-page.php
 -> index.php
 -> style.css
```

Whatever i write in style.css is shown in my front page if i don't have the front-page.php in my project (so if it picks just index.php)

If i do have front-page.php no style is shown.

I tried to write

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
?>
```

in front-page.php

I also tried to create functions.php and wrote

```
<?php
function elitetheme_enqueue_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'elitetheme_enqueue_style' );
?>
```

Still no style on my front page and it don't understand what i'm doing wrong since i just followed the documentation.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Does your front page have a `<head>` element with `<?php wp_head(); ?>`? Or inlcude a header with `get_header()` that does?

Comment: Allright, i added `<?php get_header();  ?>` in front-page.php and it started to pick the styling.
But the header also brings the title and description of my site.
Would i need to include the header on all the template files where i need style?
That is the only way to do it?

Comment: Yes. Please refer to the theme developer handbook for the proper structure of theme templates. This is all covered: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/